# (Hibernate2) GenericJDBCException: Could not execute query - Erro de sessão fechada ao navegar na plataforma

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-ee, cloud

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma aplicação web e resolvi migrar ela pra Cloud da google.
Quando inicio meu tomcat, a aplicação roda tranquila, mas a partir de um certo tempo, começa a aparecer esses erros.

```
09:24:35,719 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
09:24:35,719 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] No operations allowed after connection closed.
09:24:35,719 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
09:24:35,719 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] No operations allowed after connection closed.
09:24:35,719 ERROR [BaseDAO] Error executing query ( from net.alforria.b2c.modelo.Secao as s where s.idLoja = ? and s.id = ?).
net.sf.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute query
        at net.sf.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:90)
        at net.sf.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.convert(ErrorCodeConverter.java:79)
        at net.sf.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.convert(SessionImpl.java:4131)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:1557)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:49)
        at net.alforria.b2c.dao.BaseDAO.findByQuery(BaseDAO.java:121)
        at net.alforria.b2c.dao.ProdutoDAO.loadSecaoByLoja(ProdutoDAO.java:115)
        at net.alforria.b2c.loja.produto.ProdutoAction.listSecao(ProdutoAction.java:161)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor179.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:276)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at net.alforria.b2c.web.UrlRewriteFilter.comitaPaginaUrlAmigavel(UrlRewriteFilter.java:121)
        at net.alforria.b2c.web.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:888)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.checkClosed(Connection.java:1932)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4768)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4734)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.getPreparedStatement(BatcherImpl.java:263)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.getPreparedStatement(BatcherImpl.java:236)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.prepareQueryStatement(BatcherImpl.java:67)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:784)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:269)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:138)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1063)
        at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1054)
        at net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.list(QueryTranslator.java:854)
        at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:1554)
        ... 40 more
```

Esta é minha configuração do Hibernate 2:

```
            <!-- properties -->
            <property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/B2C</property>
            <property name="dialect">net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="show_sql">false</property>
            <!-- connection pool configurations -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">q</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">14400</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
            <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>]
```

Método findByQuery do BaseDAO:

```
protected final List findByQuery(String hql, Object[] paramValues, Type[] paramTypes) {
    List ret;
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSession();

    try {
        Query query = s.createQuery(hql);

        if(paramValues != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                Object value = paramValues[i];
                Type type = paramTypes[i];
                query.setParameter(i, value, type);
            }
        }

        ret = query.list();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e) {
        log.error("Error executing query (" + hql + ").", e);
        throw new InfraException(e);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

método loadSecaobyLoja de ProdutoDAO:

```
public Secao loadSecaoByLoja(long idLoja, long id) {
    List list = findByQuery(
        " from " + Secao.class.getName() + " as s" +
        " where s.idLoja = ? and s.id = ?",
        new Object[] {idLoja, id},
        new Type[] {Hibernate.LONG, Hibernate.LONG}
    );

    return (Secao)getFirst(list);
}
```

Comment: Poste o que for relevante do `BaseDAO` e `ProdutoDAO`   e configuração do `DataSource`.

Comment: Então... o ProdutoDAO aqui é irrelevante, pois este erro não ocorre somente em consultas de produtos... O principal problema aqui, é a conexão se fechando sozinha... É possível que seja algum erro com as configs do c3p0?

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho como dizer, somente com as informação que você postou, se o problema é o pool de conexões, configurações internas do banco / tomcat ou simplesmente a maneira como  `Session` /  `EntityManager` estão sendo injetados / usados. Jogando o seu problema no Google você encontrará todas essas variações (e algumas outras) para `MySQLNonTransientConnectionException`. Como você já incluiu configurações como `testConnectionOnCheckout=true` e `idle_test_period=100` eu testaria 1) Se suas configurações estão realmente pegando 2) Se o problema não está em outro lugar.

Comment: Escrever um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) é uma excelente maneira de isolar o problema. Isso não só irá nos ajudar a diagnosticar o problema, pode ser que você encontre a solução ao tentar isolá-lo.

Comment: Acho que você precisa descobrir o tempo que seu banco está fechando as conexoes ociosas e depois configurar o c3p0 de acordo com as informações que façam sentido no seu cenário. Não esquecer das propriedades: 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property> 
Sendo elas, todas em segundos.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda galera, tentamos aqui tudo isso e nada resolveu ainda vou colocar as informações pertinentes aqui das classes no post.

Comment: Hum... Pegar uma sessão diretamente do  `HibernateUtil` em uma aplicação web costuma dar problema. O padrão para cenários sem CDI / Spring / EJB, etc é criar um [`HibernateListener`](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingHibernatewithTomcat?_sscc=t) (opcionalmente você pode jogar também a [`SessionFactory` como atributo em escopo de aplicação](https://gist.github.com/imanoleizaguirre/3819393#file-hibernatelistener-java)). Todos os pontos de uso da aplicação devem abrir  sua própria `Session` a partir da `SessionFactory` (e fechar a sessão após o uso). Veja se isso resolve.

Comment: Adicionalmente, configure a conexão diretamente no Hibernate como sugerido acima. Com as suas configurações atuais você está usando o c3p0 em cima de um [datasource do Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources)... Além do trabalho de pooling estar sendo duplicado, o c3p0 obterá conexões *stale* caso você não configure parâmetros como `maxWait` corretamente no pool do Tomcat.

Comment: Mais uma vez agradeço o auxílio e as informações! Acho que conseguimos resolver aqui, em breve edito o post com a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Ao setar o caminho do banco basta criar um autoReconnect... Por padrão o servidor desativa a conexão após certo tempo de ociosidade! No meu caso ficou assim:

```
jdbc:mysql://caminho:3306/banco?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Então, Michel, valeu demais, mas essa configuração já está assim, olha -> url="jdbc:mysql://caminho?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=latin1"

Comment: No meu caso, resolveu de boa... Se voce remover os demais parâmetros, ele não consegue interpretar?

Comment: Então, essa url já está configurada dessa mesma forma em nosso outro servidor... E lá funciona perfeitamente! O erro começou a acontecer só nos servidores que colocamos ao migrar para a Google Cloud!